# How to close first Slidable when the second one opens?

Tags: flutter, dart

I use `Slidable` and I need to close the first `Slidable` when I open the second `Slidable`. So that I can only open one `Slidable`. How to implement it?

**code**

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Slidable(
      key: uniqueKey,
      dragStartBehavior: DragStartBehavior.start,
      endActionPane: ActionPane(
        motion: const BehindMotion(),
        extentRatio: 0.32,
        children: [
          Flexible(
            child: Row(
              children: [
                CustomSlidableAction(
                  onPressed: (value) async {},
                  backgroundColor: constants.Colors.blue,
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                    child: icon,
                  ),
                ),
                CustomSlidableAction(
                  onPressed: (value) async {},
                  backgroundColor: constants.Colors.red3,
                  child: SizedBox(
                    height: 20,
                    child: constants.Assets.trash.toSVG(),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
      child: child,
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your list of slidable with SlidableAutoCloseBehavior

[Link to the output](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LPK9bn4Dh9Fk4N5PEtDMS9qLFclnJGx6/view?usp=share_link)

Here is the example code

```dart
SlidableAutoCloseBehavior(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 100,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Slidable(
              endActionPane: ActionPane(
                motion: const ScrollMotion(),
                children: [
                  SlidableAction(
                    flex: 2,
                    onPressed: (context) { },
                    icon: Icons.delete,
                    label: 'Delete',
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text('${index + 1}'),
              )
            );
          },
        ),
      )
```